# Why is $X_{\alpha,\beta}$ a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading the paper [*Chaoticity and invariant measures for cell population module*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X12002594) by Ryszard Rudnicki, and on page 153 I do not understand why

1. $X_{\alpha,\beta}$ is Banach space,
2. $i(X_{\alpha,\beta})$ is dense in $X_{\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta}}$.

**Here are the data of the problem:**

For given $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ let $X_{\alpha,\beta}$  be a
subset of $C((0, \infty), \mathbb{R})$ which contains all functions $v$ such that
$$
  \lim_{x \to 0} x^{\alpha} |v(x)| = 0
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\beta} |v(x)| = 0.
$$

The set $X_{\alpha,\beta}$ equipped with the norm $\| v \| _{X_{\alpha,\beta}} = \sup_{x\in (0, \infty)} |v(x)| \varphi(x) $, where

$$
  \varphi(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x^{\alpha}, & \text{for $x \leq 1$}, \\
    x^{\beta},  & \text{for $x \geq 1$},
  \end{cases}
$$

is a Banach space. Convergence in the space $X_{\alpha,\beta}$ is stronger than uniform convergence on compact subsets of $(0, \infty)$. If $\bar{\alpha}>\alpha$ and $\bar{\beta}<\beta$ then $X_{\alpha,\beta} \subset  X_{\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta}}$, the inclusion $i \colon X_{\alpha,\beta} \to X_{\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta}}$, $i(v)=v$ is continuous and $i(X_{\alpha,\beta})$ being a dense
subspace of $X_{\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta}}$.

**Where I have the problem exactly:**

I tried to show the first question using the definition of Cauchy's sequence, i.e. $\sup_{x \in (0, \infty)} |v_{n}(x)-v_{m}(x)| \varphi(x) < \epsilon$, but I failed to estimate $\sup_{x\in (0, \infty)} |v_{n}(x)-v_{m}(x)| $ by $\epsilon$ to use the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ and uniform convergence.

Comment: The first thing is to find a candidate for the limit For each fixed $x$, the Cauchy condition for the weighted sup-norm together with $\varphi(x)>0$ implies that $(v_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a real Cauch sequence and hence has a limit $v(x)$. The next thing is to show continuity (which follows from the fact that your norm is stronger than uniform convergence on compact sets) and $\sup\limits_{x\in(0,\infty} |v_n(x)-v(x)|\varphi(x)=0$ (essentially, let $m\to\infty$ in the Cauchy condition. Finally, use this to show that $v$ belongs in fact to your space $X_{\alpha,\beta}$.

Comment: thank you for your comment @ Jochen . can you detail me more your answer, Because I understood in your commentary that the uniform convergence on each compact of $v_{n}$ to $v$, sufficient to show that $v$ belongs to $X_{\alpha,\beta}$ (ie $v$ continuous and $\lim_{x\to  0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\rvert v_{n}(x)\rvert x^{\alpha}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{x\to 0}\lvert v_{n}(x)\rvert x^{\alpha}=0$),how can we conclude this without the uniform convergence over the whole interval $(0,\infty)$?.  and if it is possible an indication on $i(X_{\alpha,\beta})$ dense subspace of $X_{\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta}}$,